# DynamoDB Table Query Not Sorting

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have created a table in DynamoDB that has both a primary key(string) and a sort key(number)(course-lesson-id) and I am using the following simple Lambda function to query the table where the course-lesson-id > 0:

```
import json
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

#always start with the lambda_handler
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # make the connection to dynamodb
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

    # select the table
    table = dynamodb.Table("table-name")

    response = table.query(
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('course-lesson-id').gt(0)
    )
    items = response['Items']
    print(items)
```

As I understand it, the results are supposed to be returned in numeric order based on the sort key, but I am getting the following error:

```
ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the 
Query operation: Query condition missed key schema element: course- 
lesson
```

course-lesson is the name of the primary partition key.

Any thoughts on possible causes or fixes?

Comment: It looks like it is returning values sorted by the `Key` first, then `Sort Key`.

Comment: Nope, it isnt sorting by the partition key as it isnt used for such when performing a scan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a primary key for a `Query` operation. From the [Query docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html):

> Use the `KeyConditionExpression` parameter to provide a specific value for the **partition key**. [...] You can **optionally** narrow the scope of the Query operation by specifying a **sort key** value [...]

You can't use a `Query` by only providing a sort key. If you only want to query based on the `course-lesson-id` filtering for greater than `0`, then use a `Scan` - however, take care that `Scan`s are "more expensive" in terms of resource usage, i.e. for big tables they take a lot longer to execute.